# Incorporate string with list entries - alternating

Tags: python

So SO, i am trying to "merge" a string (`a`) and a list of strings (`b`):

```
a = '1234'
b = ['+', '-', '']
```

to get the desired output (`c`):

```
c = '1+2-34'
```

The characters in the desired output string alternate in terms of origin between string and list. Also, the list will always contain one element less than characters in the string. I was wondering what the fastest way to do this is.

what i have so far is the following:

```
c = a[0]
for i in range(len(b)):
    c += b[i] + a[1:][i]
print(c)  # prints -> 1+2-34
```

But i kind of feel like there is a better way to do this..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to `zip` the two sequences, then keep iterating even after the shorter sequence ran out of characters. If you run out of characters, you'll start getting `None` back, so just consume the rest of the numerical characters.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> ''.join(i+j if j else i for i,j in zip_longest(a, b))
'1+2-34'
```

As [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) suggested in the comments, you can also pass a `fillvalue` argument to `zip_longest` which will insert empty strings. I'd suggest his method since it's a bit more readable.

```
>>> ''.join(i+j for i,j in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=''))
'1+2-34'
```

A further optimization suggested by [@ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) is to remove the temporary string concatenations (`i+j`) and replace those with an [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) call instead

```
>>> ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue='')))
'1+2-34'
```

Comment: Or `i + j for i, j in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue='')`…

Comment: @deceze Good suggestion! I edited my post to include that alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestions. is it only readability one gains by using this approach?

Comment: Perhaps performance as well since it checks a conditional? Don't know, I'd have to time it, but I suspect that conditional time is negligible.

Comment: Long as you're using `itertools`, can avoid the genexpr (and a ton of temporary two character strings), by just `join`ing all at once; import `chain` as well as `zip_longest`, and it's just: `''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue='')))`; the `chain.from_iterable` effectively "flattens" the `tuple`s from `zip_longest` so it's just generating all individual characters. Moves all the work to the C layer (in the CPython reference interpreter), which is more likely to mean performance gains.